# Moving linux partition so to be next to free space

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, ubuntu-10.10, gparted

I had a triple boot windows 7, Ubuntu 10.10 and Ubuntu 11.10.  I deleted the partition that the 11.10 was in and now I have free space on my ext4 partition.  I want to use that space which is located in my ext4 partition for my sda/5 mounted at / for my linux 10.10.  But the problem is that the free space isn't next to sda/5, its next to sda/7 which is my grub boot memory.  Is there a way to fix this I'm not sure if I can create a new partition for my home directory which would work I guess if that's possible.  I worried because I don't want to mess anything up.  Also should I use software like gparted to change partitions?

Comment: You deleted the partition and the next one is still called sda7?

Comment: I deleted sda8. The first one is sda5  next to it is sda7 the grub boot loader then the free memory and then sda6 linux swap space.

Comment: Please provide the following: sudo fdisk -l (copy paste in your question or here in the comment)

Answer (score -1):

The free space can found effectively as home directory, this can do it editing the **`fstab`** file, which found into `/etc` directory.

So you should open the **`fstab`** file (as superuser, of course) and add the follow line to end of file:

`/dev/sdaX /home ext4 nodev,nosuid 0 2`

Of course you have to rempace the X with the correct number of your future home partition.

Once this is done, just **reboot** your computer. :)

Comment: This is not a good answer because: 1. he first needs to create a partition on the new space and format it. 2. you did not include the part where he needs to BACKUP HIS OLD HOME DIR before doing what you stated.